# How can I get file details in subfolders recursively?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to compile a list of specific details about the music files on my computer, but my knowledge of VBS is limited. (Actually, I've done some VBA, but no VBS before.) I found two scripts online: one gets the file details in a folder and the other lists the names of subfolders and files recursively. I'm trying to combine the two but I'm running into problems because the first script starts with *CreateObject("Shell.Application")* and the second starts with *CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")*. This (i.e., Shell vs. FSO) is one of the areas of VBS scripting about which my knowledge is lacking, to put it mildly.

The incompatibility in my script appears in the *For Each objFile in colFiles* loop, which I inserted from the "Shell script" I referred to above. What can I do to make this script work?

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim StartFolder, FileName, fso, MyFile, Tabs, arrDetails(4)

Tabs = ""

arrDetails(0) = 0
arrDetails(1) = 1
arrDetails(2) = 27
arrDetails(3) = 28

StartFolder = "C:\Users\user\Music\MP3s"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(StartFolder)

FileName = "C:\Users\user\Documents\MP3 File Details.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForAppending, True, True)

MyFile.WriteLine objFolder.Path

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(StartFolder), Tabs, arrDetails


Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder, ByVal Tabs, arrDetails)
  Dim TabsFolder, TabsFiles, FileLine, arrText(4), i, d

  TabsFolder = Tabs & "" & vbtab & ""

  For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
    MyFile.WriteLine
    MyFile.WriteLine TabsFolder & Subfolder.Name

    TabsFiles = TabsFolder & "" & vbtab & ""

    Set objSubFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
    Set colFiles = objSubFolder.Files

    'Original inserted code for getting file details
'    For Each strFileName in objFolder.Items
'      For i = 0 to 3
'        d = arrDetails(i)
'        arrText(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, d)
'      Next
'    
'      FileLine = arrText(0)
'      For i = 1 to 3
'        FileLine = FileLine & vbtab & arrText(i)
'      Next
'      MyFile.WriteLine FileLine
'    Next

    'Attempt to make code compatible with rest of script
    For Each objFile in colFiles
      If LCase(InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".mp3")) > 1 then
        For i = 0 to 3
          d = arrDetails(i)
          arrText(i) = colFiles.GetDetailsOf(objFile, d)
        Next

        FileLine = arrText(0)
        For i = 1 to 3
          FileLine = FileLine & vbtab & arrText(i)
        Next

        MyFile.WriteLine TabsFiles & FileLine
      End If
    Next

    ShowSubFolders Subfolder, TabsFolder, arrDetails
  Next
End Sub

MyFile.Close
```

Comment: Haven't studied you code, but something I spotted is that you need to reverse `LCase` and `InStr`

Comment: @Arno You're right. I should have noticed that. That's what I get for copying something off the internet without checking it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need both the [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) and the [Windows Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-reference-bumper) object in this case. You use the FileSystemObject to loop through the folders. In each folder, you then use the Windows Shell object to get the file details.

Here's a modified `ShowSubFolders` Sub that will work as expected:

```
Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder, Tabs, arrDetails)
    Dim TabsFolder, TabsFiles, FileLine, arrText(4), i, d
    Dim objShell
    Dim objFolder
    Dim objSubfolder
    Dim objFiles
    Dim objFile
    Dim sFileName
    
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    TabsFolder = Tabs & "" & vbTab & ""
    
    For Each objSubfolder In Folder.SubFolders
    
        ' Write subfolder to file
        MyFile.WriteLine
        MyFile.WriteLine TabsFolder & objSubfolder.Name
        
        ' Increment tab position
        TabsFiles = TabsFolder & "" & vbTab & ""
        
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(objSubfolder.Path)
        Set objFiles = objSubfolder.Files
        
        For Each sFileName In objFolder.Items
            
            ' Check if file is MP3
            If InStr(1, LCase(sFileName), ".mp3") > 0 Then
            
                ' Get file details
                For i = 0 To 3
                    d = arrDetails(i)
                    arrText(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(sFileName, d)
                Next
                
                ' Build file information line
                FileLine = arrText(0)
                For i = 1 To 3
                    FileLine = FileLine & vbTab & arrText(i)
                Next
                
                ' Write file information to file
                MyFile.WriteLine TabsFiles & FileLine
            
            End If
            
        Next
        
        ' Call recursively to handle subfolders
        ShowSubFolders objSubfolder, TabsFolder, arrDetails
  
    Next

End Sub
```

The code you had commented out was good and made accessing extended file properties (like length and bitrate in your case) possible using the `arrDetails` you have.

Also included in this revised sub is the fix Arno Van Boven mentioned in the comments regarding flipping `InStr` and `LCase`.

Comment: I've made the suggested changes, but now I'm getting an error on the _For Each objSubfolder In Folder.SubFolders_ line. The error is _Object required: 'Folder'_. Am I sending that parameter to the sub incorrectly?

Comment: Your code looks correct, although you can simply use `objFolder` in your call to `ShowSubFolders`. Post your updated code in the question so we can see what you have.

Comment: I've tried it both ways with the same result. My updated script has been posted.

Comment: Never mind. I found my error and the script works perfectly now. Thanks for the help!!